# How synchronized(this) works?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've a snippet something like this,

> MyServiceConnection obj = new MyServiceConnection();

```
class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        myNotificationBinder = null;
        myBinderService.broadcastServiceIsDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinderService service) {
        synchronized(this) {
            mNotificationBinder.broadcastServiceIsUp();
                try {
                    notifyAll();
                } catch(RemoteException e) {
                   Log.e(TAG, "Remote exception : " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class `MyServiceConnection` has only one object used across my project. Consider two threads are accessing this simultaneously `t1` and `t2` but in a different manner say,

`t1` is accessing `onServiceConnected` and acquired lock on `obj`. Now will thread `t2` be able to access `onServiceDisconnected` before `t1` completes its execution in `onServiceConnected`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `onServiceDisconnected` is not synchronized, then `t2` won't be blocked when calling it. Synchronization only affects other threads that synchronize on the same object. The object used with the synchronized keyword doesn't have any special meaning beyond this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to call any other method and execute any other code outside of synchronized(this). Unless other code in your class calls synchronized(this) this code could be executed by any number of threads simultaniously